# Update attribute isn't working for my ids list?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

On my site you can open sessions, and add instruments to the session. An admin (the person who creates the session) can choose what instruments are in the session.

**In this example we** will say "The admin wants the following instruments: 1, 1 again and instrument 2". So far everything proceed as expected but then... #{start.exciting.music.now}

The admin wants to add another instrument but if the instrument already exist you can't add it again?

**Edit form**

```
  .col-xs-12.item
    %hr
    %ul#instrument-selection.instrument-list
      = link_to instruments_path, class: 'fancybox' do
        %li
          = image_tag('plus.png', class: 'fit')
          Add instrument
      - @meeting.instruments.each do |instrument|
        %li
          = image_tag(instrument.icon_path)
          = instrument.name
          %input{type: 'hidden', value: instrument.id, name: 'meeting[instrument_ids][]'}
          %i.fa.fa-times.delete-me
```

**What you open when you click on the fancy box link**

```
%section#musician-listing
  .col-xs-12.item
    .musician-badge
      %ul.musician-info
        - @instruments.each do |instrument|
          %li.col-xs-12.item
            .col-xs-6
              = image_tag(instrument.icon_path, class: 'fit instrument-icons')
            .col-xs-6
              = link_to '#', class: 'btn btn-success fit square add-instrument', data: {instrument_id: instrument.id, name: instrument.name, icon: "/#{instrument.icon_path}"} do
                Add
                = instrument.name
        .clearboth
```

**Meeting controller**

```
  def create
    meeting = current_user.meetings.create( meeting_params )
    if meeting.valid?
      redirect_to meeting
      flash[:notice] = "Succesfully created session"
    else
      redirect_to new_meeting_path
      flash[:alert] = "Oops.. You haven't filled in the required information"
    end
  end
  def update
    meeting = current_user.meetings.find(params[:id])
    meeting.update_attributes(meeting_params)

    redirect_to meeting
    flash[:notice] = "Succesfully edited session"
  end
```

**The output when updating the meeting (seems fine I guess)**

```
Started PATCH "/meetings/163" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-18 22:29:41 +0200
Processing by MeetingsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZJvwuX3x4f7cACp5N75IOEn7zczO4qyevmxydiN+LF+AZnys11kioeAbUU/jwlc76+mAdN2c2vvZKFpgg+6vPA==", "meeting"=>{"title"=>"Test2", "closed_session"=>"false", "genre_id"=>"2", "instrument_ids"=>["1", "1", "1", "1", "2"], "user_ids"=>["2"]}, "commit"=>"Update session", "id"=>"163"}
```

**Now the weird part!**

Even if the "instrument_ids" returns ["1", "1", "1", "1", "2"] it just removes the 3th and the 4th "1" and it keeps the "2".

If we would update it again (before updating the array is ["1", "1", "2"]) and for example we add another "2" and a "5" and another "1", the PATCH command will return ["1", "1", "2", "2", "5", "1"] but it will end up with ["1", "1", "2", "5"].

**Again everything what already exist is removed**

If you create a new meeting you can add as much the same ids if you like.

**Any help would be much appreciated it's driving me mad....**

Cheers,
Chris

P.S. staring at this issues for almost 12 hours... haha damn....

**Meeting.rb**

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :genre
  acts_as_votable
  has_many :user_meetings
  has_many :users, through: :user_meetings

  has_many :meeting_instruments
  has_many :instruments, through: :meeting_instruments

  has_many :likes, through: :user_meetings, source: :user

  validates :title, :genre_id, :meeting_instruments, presence: true

  scope :ordered, -> { order(updated_at: :desc) }

  mount_uploader :preview, PreviewUploader

  def clean_users
    meeting_instruments.unavailable.where('user_id not in (?)', user_ids).update_all(user_id: nil)
  end

  def artists
    users + User.find(meeting_instruments.pluck(:user_id) - [nil])
  end

  def musicians
    "#{users.first.musician_name} (+#{artists.count - 1})"
  end

  def timelines
    meeting_instruments.unavailable.map(&:timeline)
  end

  def openings
    return 'None' unless meeting_instruments.available.any?
    Instrument.find(meeting_instruments.available.pluck(:instrument_id)).map(&:name).join(', ')
  end

  def join(user_id, instrument_id)
    meeting_instrument = meeting_instruments.available.find_by(instrument_id: instrument_id)
    meeting_instrument.update_attributes(user_id: user_id)
    meeting_instrument.create_timeline(user_id: user_id)
  end

  def wav_files
    files = []

    timelines.map(&:source_url).each do |uri|
      destination = Tempfile.new(["output_#{id}", '.wav'])
      destination_path = destination.path
      destination.unlink

      source = Tempfile.new("source_#{id}")

      open(source.path, 'wb') do |file|
        file << open(uri).read
      end

      `ffmpeg -i #{ source.path.shellescape } #{ destination_path.shellescape }`
      files << destination_path
    end
    files
  end

  def publish
    file = Tempfile.new(["output_#{id}", '.mp3'])
    files = wav_files
    if files.count > 1
      combiner = Sox::Combiner.new(files, combine: :mix, norm: true)
      combiner.write file.path
      File.open file.path
    else
      File.open files.first
    end
  end

  def load_preview
    Resque.enqueue(PreviewLoader, self.id)
  end
end
```

**And meeting_instrument.rb**

```
class MeetingInstrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meeting
  belongs_to :instrument
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :timeline

  scope :available, -> { where(user_id: nil) }
  scope :unavailable, -> { where('user_id is not ?', nil) }

  def open?
    user_id.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: at which point the 3rd and 4th value gets dropped? Is it after reading from the controller?

Comment: You could shorten your question substantially if you get the same behaviour on in the console, `meeting.instrument_ids = ["1", "2", "1"]; meeting.save!` exhibited the same behaviour. You could then delete all that view/controller code from the question. Possibly worth posting how the associations are defined.

Comment: Hey, thx for replying. I will try both suggestions tonight. 

It happens after saving, the console get the values correct.

Comment: Hey everyone, I still don't know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I updated the question with the asked models.